# In ggplot2, how can I seperately plot four group of one csv file in barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am a beginner in R. I have one question.

I am trying to make the multiple bar a[image]

For doing this, I am using the below data

```
gender party      likes_count
<chr>  <chr>               <dbl>
1 F      D              587.
2 F      R              180.
3 M      D              335.
4 M      R              177.


  gender party      comments_count
  <chr>  <chr>             <dbl>
1 F      D             155. 
2 F      R             18.2
3 M      D             71.7
4 M      R             34.6

  gender party      haha_count
  <chr>  <chr>             <dbl>
1 F      D            84.4
2 F      R            81.9
3 M      D            53.8
4 M      R            64.7

 gender party      wow_count
  <chr>  <chr>             <dbl>
1 F      D            84.4
2 F      R            81.9
3 M      D            53.8
4 M      R            64.7
```

How can I make the above picture using this data?
Many thanks,

Comment: Please follow the instructinos at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and show the output of `dput(X)` for each input data frame X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question, you are looking for `facetting` graph. There are many questions / answers on SO about this subject.

In order to get your graph, first you have to manipulate your dataset in order to be ready for plotting with ggplot2.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(., -c(gender,party),names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>% mutate(New_Col = paste0(party, "-",gender))
df$Variable = factor(df$Variable, levels = c("likes", "comments", "haha", "wow"))
```

Then for plotting, you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = New_Col, y = Value, fill = New_Col)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  facet_wrap(.~ Variable, scales = "free")
```

And you get the following graph

[image]

Hope it answers your question.

**Data**

```r
df = data.frame(gender = c("F","F","M","M"),
                party = c("D","R","D","R"),
                likes = c(587,189,335,177),
                comments = c(155,18.2,71.7,34.6),
                haha = c(84.4,81.9,53.8,64.7),
                wow = c(84.4,81.9,53.8,64.7))
```